kubectl error: memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
I am facing this error when executing kubectl get pods

E0624 13:36:13.519657   14966 memcache.go:265]
couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials


I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed on Win.
Cluster is hosted in AWS EKS
I have configured aws configure properly
kubeconfig has the right cluster API
Context is properly set up

Output of kubectl config view is:
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://5D85B785D486061508D49C040E602E31.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:622201584709:cluster/eks-mundos-e
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:622201584709:cluster/eks-mundos-e
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:622201584709:cluster/eks-mundos-e
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:622201584709:cluster/eks-mundos-e
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:622201584709:cluster/eks-mundos-e
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:622201584709:cluster/eks-mundos-e
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eks-mundos-e
      - --output
      - json
      command: aws
      env: null
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false

Any advice?
